# How do I find out the distance between turtles in Netlogo so as I can do some operations

Tags: netlogo

I am writing a Net-logo simulation where I have a following condition

"One turtle is green in color and rest of the others are in grey now I need to fire a query that if a grey agent comes in contact of green agent than its color changes"

Comment: Did you do any work on this yourself, or write any code yourself? If so, can you tell us what you found out or what you tried? Did you look in the NetLogo Dictionary to see if there are any primitives that have to do with distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we assume that "comes in contact" means "stands on the same patch with", and suppose we assume "its color changes" means "it turns red". Then:

```
ask turtles [
  if any? other turtles-here with [color = green] [
    set color red
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let green-agent one-of turtles with [color = green]
ask turtles with [color = grey and distance green-agent < 1] [set color (random 255)
```